# Ionic 3 where declare global function

Tags: ionic3, global

I have a function `xyz` that I want to access from multiple pages. Where and how should I put/declare the function? And how do I call the function?

Comment: They are talking about variables, I am talking about functions

Comment: this is exactly the same methodology, the simpler will be to create a service that all the controllers which need the function will import. Actually i think that in the example he does it with functions, the OP complaining the same way that he needed variables ;)